# Bloquear acesso direto a uma página

Tags: php, login, redirecionamento

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site em PHP no qual há uma tela de login, que redireciona para a tela do admin, mas se tento acessar essa tela do admin direto pela url, ela abre normalmente.

Eu gostaria de bloquear esse acesso direto pela url, redirecionando para a tela do login. Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Session PHP. Tem no seu site ?

Comment: No início eu tava usando Session, mas tava dando uns erros, aí eu mudei

Answer (score 11, accepted):

De maneira mais simples, se você usa o PHP puro, você pode fazer assim:

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    return header('location: login.php');
}
```

O `empty` já avaliará se o valor de `admin` existe e ao mesmo tempo se ele é um booleano. Se for falso e/ou se não existir, o usuário será redirecionado para página de login (ou qualquer outra que quiser redirecionar);

**Nota**: Por causa dos comentários críticos a respeito da utilização do `empty`, faço um esclarecimento: não utilizo o `isset` porque geraria código desnecessário e não se aplicaria ao caso.

Utilizando a função `empty` tratamos ao mesmo tempo dois problemas: O caso da pessoa não estar logada, ou seja, a variável `$_SESSION['admin']`não existir; E o caso de a variável possuir valor `false`, pois nesse caso `empty` retorna `false` para valores do tipo `false` - e se o usuário não é admin não pode ver a página.

Eu utilizaria o `isset` apenas para tratar dois tipos de casos diferentes.

Por exemplo : diferenciar usuário não-logado do usuário logado que não é admin.

```
session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['admin']) {
   return header('location: pagina_de_usuario_nao_logado.php');
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == false) {
    return header('location: pagina_de_logado_mas_nao_eh_admin.php');
}
```

Se eu utilizasse a mesma forma que utilizei no primeiro exemplo, tratando com `isset`, o código teria que ficar assim:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['admin']) || $_SESSION['admin'] == false) {
     // ...
}
```

Veja como seria desnecessário o uso de `isset`, se fossemos substituir a primeira forma.

Comment: Testei aqui e tá dando esse erro "syntax error, unexpected '{' in.."

Comment: Faltou um `)` que fecha o if.

Comment: Funcinou, Obrigado :D

Comment: O @DeeSouza deu um tapa no código.

Comment: Não precisa, a resposta ta certa, é +1.

Comment: valeu @rray :) :)

Comment: precisa usar isset() antes do empty().

Comment: Não precisa. Se a variável não existir, empty retorna false. Se ela existir e for falsa, retornará false. Se ela existir e tiver valor true, retorna true. Não há necessidade de isset. empty também faz esse trabalho.

Comment: Não é necessário usar o `empty`, para sessão utiliza simplesmente `isset`, o `empty` é apenas para o caso de o valor ter sido definido para `NULL`.

Comment: Amigos, desculpem, mas acho que vocês não sabem do que estão falando. `empty` verifica se um valor vazio. O php considera vazio array vazio, null, false, 0, string vazia e variável ou índice não existente. Não tem nada errado no código.  http://php.net/empty